# CMD stops after pressing enter key to obtain code result

Tags: java

This is a program based on a book identifier no. Now, when I run it in CMD  and input ISBN, then after pressing enter CMD stops and doesn't show the result. Moreover it stops taking any other [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YgME.png) input.  Below is my code and link to screenshot of CMD. Thanks.

```java
/*
The international standard book number(ISBN) is a unique numeric book identifier which is printed on every book.
THe ISBN is based upon a 10-digit code. THe ISBN is legal if:
1*digit1+2*digit2+3*digit3+4*digit4+5*digit5+6*digit6+7*digit7+8*digit8+9*digit9+10*digit10 is divisible by 11.
Exaample : for an ISBN 1401601499,Sum=1*1+2*4+3*0+4*1+5*6+6*0+7*1+8*4+9*9+10*(=254 Which is divisible by 11.

Write a program to:
(i)Input the ISBN codes as a 10-digit integre
(ii)Input the ISBN is not a 10-digit integer,output message "Illegal ISBN" and terminate the program.
(iii)If the number is divisible by 11 output the message"Legal ISBN". If the sum is not divisible by 11,output the message "Illegal ISBN".
*/

import java.util.*; // package name. 

class BookNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the ISBN : ");
        long isbn = sc.nextLong();
        long r;
        long d = 0;
        long s = 0;
        long num = isbn;
        while (num != 0) //digit count logic 
        {
            ++d;
            num = num / 10; //it remove the last digit 
        }
        if (d == 10)
        {
            while (isbn != 0)
            {
                r = num % 10; //it extract the last digit
                s = s + r * d--;
                num = num / 10;
            }
            if (s % 11 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Legal ISBN");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Illegal ISBN");
            }
        }
    } // End of main 
} //End of class
```

Comment: The `while (isbn != 0)` loop does not change or even access the `isbn` - variable.

Comment: According to the Web site [International ISBN Agency](https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn): _ISBNs were 10 digits in length up to the end of December 2006, but since 1 January 2007 they now always consist of 13 digits._

Answer (score 1):

I think your `while (isbn != 0)` is an infinite loop. If you don't change the `isbn` variable inside the body, it will run indefinitely.

Comment: You're right, probably the `num` variable inside the `while` cycle has to be `isbn` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `num` to `isbn` at the start of the second loop.
Also you should give an error message when the length of the ISBN is not 10.

```
import java.util.*; // package name. 

public class BookNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the ISBN : ");
        long isbn = sc.nextLong();
        long r;
        long d = 0;
        long s = 0;
        long num = isbn;
        while (num != 0) //digit count logic 
        {
            ++d;
            num = num / 10; //it remove the last digit 
        }
        if (d == 10)
        {
            num = isbn;
            while (num != 0)
            {
                r = num % 10; //it extract the last digit
                s = s + r * d--;
                num = num / 10;
            }
            if (s % 11 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Legal ISBN");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Illegal ISBN");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Illegal ISBN");
        }
    } // End of main 
} //End of class
```